# What does the opposite outcome of Unity Math.Clamp()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clamp

Is there a method of making sure a integer can't be between two numbers, kind of like Unity's `Mathf.Clamp()` method but instead of not allowing it to be above or below two numbers, make sure its not between two numbers.

Comment: I don't know of any such function, but it would be trivial to write yourself once you decide what the rules are.

Comment: I was just wondering, it would be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not between the two numbers, what should it be - the upper value or the lower value? If you want the closest, you could do:

```
int ClosestIfBetween(int val, int low, int high)
{
    if (val > low && val < high)
    {
        int mid = (high - low) / 2 + low;
        return val < mid ? low : high;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Yea, it would be the closest too. I already have a method of doing this but I wanted to know if it was possible. Kind of sucks that there is no opposite of ```Mathf.Clamp()```